# Connect WD TV Live Hub

Tags: networking, external-hdd

I have a PC (pc1) running Ubuntu 12.10, connected to the router wirelessly. 
A WD TV live hub is connected to PC using a crossover ethernet cable.

Configuration:
Wired connection method: shared to other computers and "Require IPv4 addressing for this connection to complete" is checked.

The  WD TV Live Hub has IP address 10.42.0.22 using DHCP and it has internet.

My problem is that I can't see the WD TV Live hub from other PCs (excluded pc1).

If I set a static IP (192.168.1.xx) to WD TV Live hub, it hasn't internet.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you practically "hide" the TV Live Hub behind PC1 it will not be possible (without some tricks) for the other PCs to see it.

As for the IP address: the TV Hub uses the connection to PC1 it must have a correct IP address for that network (via crossover). So leave that address well alone.